# Solr search multiple fields including field association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have the following classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
       text :full_name, boost: 3.0
       text :about_me
       join(:name, target: Nickname, type: :text, join: { from: :user_id, to: :id })
    end
end

class Nickname < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
        text :name
        integer :user_id
    end
end
```

What I would like to do is to search for a user by its full_name, about_me or has a nickname with the searched email.

I tried the following and I never get a result:

```
 User.search { fulltext 'FrodoBaggings' }.results
 User.search { fulltext 'FrodoBaggings'; fulltext 'Frodo', fields: [:name] }
 User.search do 
     any do
         fulltext 'Frodo Baggings', fields: [:full_name, :about_me]
         fulltext 'Frodo Baggings', fields: [:name]
     end
 end
```

Comment: try keywords instead of fulltext....

Comment: it is not working, care to give an example?